# Question concerning the segment addition postulate.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I am using Geometry by Ray C. Jurgensen ( book is from the 90's ). The book states as postulate 2 on page 12 that

If $B$ is between $A$ and $C$, then

$$ AB + BC = AC $$

My question is this: Is this simply a conditional in the forward direction? Or do we treat this postulate as bi conditional statement. In other words, does it follow from this postulate that the converse statement below also holds?

$$ \text{If } AB + BC = AC \text{, then } B \text{ is between } A \text{ and } C. $$

I have the same question concerning postulate 4 - Angel Addition Postulate on page 18, which states that

If point $B$ lies in the interior of $\angle ABC,$ then

$$ m\angle AOB + m\angle BOC = m\angle AOC$$.

Thank you for your time and consideration in advance.

Comment: The other direction is a theorem. You can prove it from the axioms.

Comment: for the first one, the converse is true, for the second one, the converse is true for except when $m\angle AOC = 180^o$. You can have $B$ on the other side of the line (not including the angle), still the equation would work out well.

Comment: You have a funny "Angel addition" : it should give a better World...

Comment: I sure hope so Jean Marie lol.